# Are error code tags allowed on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed the tag [mysql-error-1193](/questions/tagged/mysql-error-1193) tag. After doing a search on the tag page, it turns out that there are fifty different [mysql-error-errornum](/questions/tagged/mysql-error-errornum) tags. I then noticed the similar [http-status](/questions/tagged/http-status) tags. Are the HTTP status tags the exception, or the rule?

Comment: and an earlier one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code. Personally, As long as they're used correctly it's a Good Thing. Generic errors (404 etc) don't count in my support for these tags.